# Select records as column (sub array) from joins or sub query

Tags: mysql, sorting, zend-framework, join, group-by

I have my tables

```
companies (id)
purchase_invoice (id,company_id,date)
items(id,company_id,purchase_invoice_id)
gifted_items(id,company_id,purchase_invoice_id)
rebated_items(id,company_id,purchase_invoice_id)
return_items(id,company_id,purchase_invoice_id)
```

I need to Query all purchase invoices of company and their associated records in other tables where company_id is equal to (user selected ).
I need all these sub tables result  as sub columns  (idk if i am correct).

Note : company_id and purchase_invoice_id are FK in all other tables

This is what I am trying

```
 $ledgers = array(
            'com'   => $data['company_id'],
            'sd'    => $data['start_date'],
            'ed'    => $data['end_date']
        );
$purchaseObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Ledgers();
$purchaseRes = $purchaseObj->getPurchaseInvoices($ledgers);


public function getPurchaseInvoices($ledgers) {
    $sql = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('pi' => $this->_name))
            ->join(array('c' => 'companies'), 'pi.company_id = c.id', array('c.name as companyName'))
            ->join(array('it' => 'items'), 'it.purchase_invoice_id = pi.id');

          //  ->join(array('prm' => 'rebated_purchase_mobiles'), 'prm.company_id = pi.company_id')
           // ->join(array('rpm' => 'returned_purchase_mobiles'), 'rpm.company_id = pi.company_id')
           // ->join(array('pgm' => 'purchase_gifted_mobiles'), 'pgm.company_id = pi.company_id');

$sql = $sql->where('pi.company_id  = ?', $ledgers['com']);  

    if (count($ledgers)) {
        if (Performance_Engine::notEmpty($ledgers['sd']) && $ledgers['sd'] != 'sd') {
            $dt = new DateTime($ledgers['sd']);
            $sdate = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
            $sql = $sql->where('CAST(pi.date AS DATE) >= ?', $sdate);
        }
        if (Performance_Engine::notEmpty($ledgers['ed']) && $ledgers['ed'] != 'ed') {
            $dt = new DateTime($ledgers['ed']);
            $edate = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
            $sql = $sql->where('CAST(pi.date AS DATE) <= ?', $edate);
        }
          $sql->group('pi.id');
        $sql->order('pi.id ASC');

        return $sql->query()->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

**I need result like below array**

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 102
        [company_id] => 8
        [grand_total_price] => 45000
        [disc_by_rupees] => 111
        [disc_by_percent] => 0
        [total_price] => 44889
        [pay_amount] => 15000
        [total_paid_amount] => 15000
        [remaining_amount] => 29889
        [bill_no] => Q13
        [date] => 2015-01-15
        [companyName] => QMobile
        [items]=> array(
                [0] => array(
                   'id' => 1
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
                   'model_id' => 1
                   'date' => 2015-12-1
                   'IMEI'=>7654367876
                   'color' => black     
                   'purchase_price' => 500
                   'is_sold' => 1
                   'is_returned'=>1
               )

               [1] => array(
                   'id' => 2
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
                   'model_id' => 3
                   'date' => 2015-12-1
                   'IMEI'=>34567890
                   'color' => white
                   'purchase_price' => 6500
                   'is_sold' => 1
                   'is_returned'=>1
               )

       )
       [gifted_items]=> array(
                [0] => array(
                   'id' => 1
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )

               [1] => array(
                   'id' => 2
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )
       )
       [rebated_items]=> array(
                [0] => array(
                   'id' => 1
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )

               [1] => array(
                   'id' => 2
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )
       )
      [return_items]=> array(
                [0] => array(
                   'id' => 1
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )

               [1] => array(
                   'id' => 2
                   'company_id'=> 8
                   'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               )
       )
 )
```

I hope this is understand. please correct me what i need to do. 
**All I need to do is purchase invoice and all associated table as column which will contain array of selected records**

Comment: Could you share a sample data from the tables and a sample output depending on user input?

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible in a query.